# Javascript cant be executed in PHP IF-Clause

Tags: javascript, php

I've got a problem that I cant get JavaScript to run inside a PHP IF-Clause.

I've got a simple upload script that I got from somewhere and modified it.

The problem is now that every bit of JavaScript outside the IF-Clause runs but nothing inside.

Heres my code:

Filename: upload.php

```html
<?php
$uploadFolder = "uploads/";
$newfolder = $uploadFolder.round(microtime(true))."/";
if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0)
{
 $file_extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $filename = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
 $url = "http://example.com";
 if(!file_exists($newfolder))
 {
  mkdir($newfolder, 0777);
 }
 $newFile = $newfolder.$filename.".".$file_extension;
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], $newFile);
 $file = fopen($newfolder."who", "a");
 $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 echo fwrite($file, $ip);
 echo fwrite($file, "\n".date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time())."\n");
 fclose($file);
 $nurl = $url."/".$newfolder;
 echo "<script>location.href='$nurl'</script>";
}
?>

<html>

 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>SKO-Gaming Upload Form</title>

  <!-- Google web fonts -->
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700" rel='stylesheet' />

  <!-- The main CSS file -->
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>

 <body>
  <form id="upload" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div id="drop">
    Drop Here
    <a>Browse</a>
    <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
   </div>

   <ul>

   </ul>

  </form>
        
  <!-- JavaScript Includes -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery File Upload Dependencies -->
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
  
  <!-- Our main JS file -->
  <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

If I put the echo stuff (with the javascript) outside the if-clause it works, but I want the user to get redirected after the file upload is finished.

Greetings,
Martin

Comment: Use `header` php function.

Comment: the header php function is also only working outside the if-clause - I somehow cant use it inside.

Comment: Did you check that you enter your if-clause?

Comment: As soon as I drop the file into the upload window - it created the folder with the epoch time and puts the file into the folder. So yeah - im pretty sure that I enter the if-clause

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to redirect the user using Javascript and not PHP?
Change your echo "..." with

```
header('Location: '.$nurl);
exit;
```

And you should get what you need.

Comment: Nope - using header isnt working. The only way I've got working is using javascript but not inside the if-clause

Comment: If I put the header outside the if-clause it also works - but not inside the if-clause

Comment: There are to reason why it should not works as you expect:
1) you are not entering the IF clause
2) you are printing something before the header function so this function raise a "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by". Add a "ini_set('display_errors', 1);" after the opening of the PHP script and you'll got more details about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the issue is here.

```
echo "<script>location.href='$nurl'</script>";
```

change it to

```
echo "<script>window.location.href=".$nurl."</script>";
```

.-> string concatenate.
use " instead of '

Comment: Nope - Even if I change it to window.location.href and change it to ".$nurl." its still not working. Only when I put it outside the if-clause (but then "location.href" is also working)

Answer (score 0):

Besides hat you are saying "Nope" to all answers, yes

```
 header('Location: '.$nurl);
 exit;
```

is the solution to your problem. And here is the part, why it don't work for you:

```
echo fwrite($file, $ip);
echo fwrite($file, "\n".date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time())."\n");
```

There is your output before your header. Remove the echo and you are fine. (Except you have more output before.

Comment: I removed the echo stuff but its still not working. It even shows me that there was an error with the upload now.

Comment: And what does it say?

Comment: Well - it only shows that the upload failed - it doesnt show any error messages.

Comment: I just noticed that the file gets uploaded - but it doesnt redirect.

Comment: I think you have rather a problem with the integration of your jquery.fileupload.js script. Maybe have a look at the docs of it. I can assure you, that calling POST on the "upload.php" with a file attached to it will redirect you to the file.